# How to install Tensorflow for C dependency on docker in linux

Tags: docker, tensorflow, dockerfile, tensorflow-c++

I am new to Docker and I am trying to install Tensorflow for C since a package I am trying to run requires the dependency `#include <tensorflow/c/c_api.h>`.

I am not sure about what to add to the Dockerfile to properly install this dependency.

I tried `apt get install -y libtensorflow-dev` but that did not work. Any help would be greatly appreciated